# SQL How to find overlap session id based on ip address? best way to rewrite self join

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

This is my dataset and want to find overlap session based on source ip address.
for example, record id =1(self),2,3,4,5 are overlap session for rec id=1
record_id = 3,4 are overlap session for rec_id=3

[image]

to find overlap session, written the sql based on self join. using self join, i am able get desired output. but issue with performance. It is taking longer time to get the result.
Now i want to do some optimization on sql query.  Please advice how to improve.
My desired final result as follow.

[image]

sql query

```
with data1 as (
select 
    left_table.*,right_table.session_id as overlap_session_id
from 
    data left_table
inner join data right_table on left_table.source_ip = right_table.source_ip
where 
    (right_table.session_start_time >= left_table.session_start_time and right_table.session_start_time <= left_table.session_end_time)
    or 
    (right_table.session_end_time >= left_table.session_start_time and right_table.session_end_time <= left_table.session_end_time)
)
select 
rec_id,session_start_time,session_end_time,source_ip,session_id,login_user
,string_agg(overlap_session_id,',') as overlap_session_id 
from data1
group by rec_id,session_start_time,session_end_time,source_ip,session_id,login_user
order by rec_id
```

Comment: will recursive CTE boost my sql execution performance.. any thought on this

Comment: From site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: Your question contains tags for `postgresql` and `google-cloud-bigquery`, can you confirm which database you are using?

Comment: The goal would be to improve the equality comparisons, so one thing might be in your inner join, and right_table.session_id <>left_table.session_id. But the real improvement probably can come if you could somehow bucket the records into blocks of time where you know you'd have no overlap...... check out this excellent post "Binned Range join" you wont be able to implement this directly but you can understand the concept and maybe come up with something that helps https://select.dev/posts/snowflake-range-join-optimization